# Why jquery click event not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. default.aspx
   click on the + symbol to increase the quantity. and - symbol for decrease the quantity.

   ```
       <div class="sp-quantity">
                                           <div class="sp-minus fff">
                                               <a class="ddd" href="#">-</a>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="sp-input">
                                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="popuptextbox quntity-input"
                                                   Width="30px" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity")%> '></asp:TextBox>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="sp-plus fff">
                                               <a class="ddd" href="#">+</a>
                                           </div>
                                           <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdateQuantity" runat="server" CommandName="Update"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color:#00374A"></i></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                       </div>



   jquery:

   <script type="text/javascript">
           $(".ddd").on("click", function () {

               var $button = $(this);
               var oldValue = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvItems_txtQuantity").val();
               //var oldValue = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvItems_txtQuantity").val();

               if ($button.text() == "+") {
                   var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
               } else {
                   if (oldValue > 0) {
                       var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
                   } else {
                       newVal = 0;
                   }
               }

               $button.closest("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvItems_txtQuantity").val(newVal);

                   });

       </script>
   ```

   In this when I click on the + symbol no event firing.How do i do with that jquery?

Comment: Wrap your jquery in $(function(){ [script here] }); - this will wait until ondocumentready so you know jquery can access the dom

Comment: Have you included jQuery library... is there any error in your console...

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()` :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".ddd").on("click", function () {
         ...
      })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your jQuery stuff, inside this function

```
$(function() {
    //jQuery stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your jquery code inside head section its just counts in best practices and one thing more add this code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 });
```

this will attach the events to the elements of given class when you document is ready and fully loaded/Dom is ready.

Comment: javascript in head is not a best practice. Best loading times are when script is last to load at end of body....this is well documented ...all the search engines and page speed tools recommend this